# How does randomisation balance known and unknown heterogeneity?

Tags: experiment-design, clinical-trials, random-allocation

Randomised controlled trials are understood to balance known and unknown heterogeneity across groups. Beyond the a posteriori point that 'randomisation looks like it balances groups' how do we know it does a priori? And, if there is an accessible answer to that question, then who was responsible for figuring it out and how?

Comment: Just as a starter, you can look here https://books.google.it/books?id=Wy0hy4DPEPQC and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3136079/